# How do I determine the identity of a UITableView within a Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, identity

I have created a TableView within the Storyboard.  I don't want to control-drag links between this and files as programmatically, this is easier to maintain.

However, I don't know how I can determine what the identity of the TableView is within the Scene.

Is there a way of naming this, or somehow determining this sop that I can dynamically change the behaviour of it?

In fact, this sort of applies to everything in the Storyboard. I don't know how to name anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tag, under the View category:

[image]

Every view (control) has it. You can use `viewWithTag` method of `UIView` to get the control you need, like this:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like something that might work.  At the moment, I can't know that this works since I can't get the [myTableView reloadData] to work.  However, I'm sure the problem is something else I am missing.  I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your storyboard, when selecting a view controller there is a screen like this in the "Identity inspector" tab:

[image]

After assigning a storyboard ID to your view controller and activate the "Use Storyboard ID" option, you can instantiate it programatically with:

```
    ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerID"];
   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That looks interesting and I can see myself using this for TableView Controls (thanks), but I don't see one of these for a TableView.  The answer below looks more promising.

Comment: Sorry, I understood you were working with the entire view controller. Good luck!